# Typesafe Activator compilation error

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

I'm using Typesafe Activator on Ubuntu 13.04. It was working, but when I create a new project sometimes it doesn't do anything and sometimes it reports that the template is cloned (without downloading anything). When the project is created I get the following compile error:

> Refreshing list of source files to watch for changes...
>
> Loading project definition from
>   /home/myusername/activator-play-autosource-reactivemongo/project
>
> Set current project to activator-play-autosource-reactivemongo (in
>   build file:/home/myusername/activator-play-autosource-reactivemongo/)
>
> Applying State transformations com.typesafe.sbtrc.SetupSbtChild from
>   """/home/myusername/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/com.typesafe.sbtrc/sbt-rc-probe-0-12/1.0-28edcfb4984c8be5e556bad192b62551504aa23d/sbt-rc-props-1.0-28edcfb4984c8be5e556bad192b62551504aa23d.jar:/home/myusername/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/com.typesafe.sbtrc/sbt-rc-probe-0-12/1.0-28edcfb4984c8be5e556bad192b62551504aa23d/sbt-rc-probe-0-12-1.0-28edcfb4984c8be5e556bad192b62551504aa23d.jar"""
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.sbtrc.SetupSbtChild$
>
> Use 'last' for the full log.
>
> Failed to reload source file list: sbt process never got in touch, so
>   unable to handle request WatchTransitiveSourcesRequest(true)

Comment: Is this question solved/answered from your point of view, or is there still s.th. unclear?

Comment: @MartinGrotzke - No it's still there :(

Answer (score 6):

In `project/build.properties` change the sbt.version from `0.12.3` to `0.13.0` (or `0.12.4` alternatively).

I just had the same issue, for me this fixed it.

Comment: changing to 0.13.0 yields to other issues, among those incompatibilities with `sbt-rc-defaults-0-12`

Comment: I got `(*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.1.1: not found` after changing the SBT version.

Comment: In my `project/plugins.sbt` the sbt-plugin is disabled, it looks like this: `//addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.1")`

Comment: Try:
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")`

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted all the activator generated files and it worked fine for me with following

In build.sbt:
   `scalaVersion := "2.10.4"`

In project/plugin.sbt:
   `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")`

Activator version: 1.1.3